# globals declarations with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Does the following style of declaration do anything in TypeScript files?

```
/* globals console define require React async */
```

or is there a different way to do this with TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it has no effect on TypeScript compiler.

What globals are currently in scope is typically selected by choosing one of the predefined library settings in typescript compiler options, for example this command line

```
tsc --lib es5,dom
```

brings into global scope everything declared in files `lib.es5.d.ts` and `lib.dom.d.ts` which are supplied with the compiler.

If you look into `lib.dom.d.ts` you can see how for example `window` is declared there:

```
declare var window: Window;
```

`Window` is an interface defined earlier in that file.

You can do the same for your own global variables - you can create your own `.d.ts` file containing `declare var` at the top level, and include that file in compilation either on command line or adding it to `files` in `tsconfig.json`.

[Everything you installed in `node_modules/@types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) is also included in compilation by default, so every global declared by these typings is also in scope, unless you limit it by setting "typeRoots"  or "types" in `tsconfid.json`.

Also, if you use some library with `import`, it will add all globals declared in that library type declaration file (and also in type declaration files from all its dependencies referenced with `import` or `/// reference` directive).